# Handle if statements and variables with awk

Tags: awk, numeric-data, data

I am trying to get data from a file that is like this:

```
  6   6   1   0
  0.1166667E+02  0.4826611E-09  0.4826611E-09  0.3004786E-09  0.5000000E-15
  1.000000000000000E-004
  CAR 
 system-001                       
     10.51965443    -34.96542345  301      1.95329810      1.00000000
-15.558  0.1631E+01  0.1597E+02
-15.407  0.1661E+02  0.1779E+02
-15.255  0.4253E+01  0.1990E+02
-15.104  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
-14.952  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
 -3.884  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
 -3.732  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
 -3.581  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
 -3.429  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
 -3.277  0.8214E-03  0.2000E+02
 -3.126  0.3543E+00  0.2002E+02
  1.726  0.1019E+01  0.4386E+02
  1.877  0.5581E+00  0.4399E+02
  2.029  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.181  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.332  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.484  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.636  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.787  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.939  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.090  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.242  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.394  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.545  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.697  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.849  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  4.000  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  4.152  0.6271E-01  0.4400E+02
  4.303  0.4520E+01  0.4433E+02
  4.455  0.5040E+01  0.4511E+02
```

I want to take always the fourth column from the 6 line (1.95329810 in this case), then look for its closest value in the following lines, from the first column(1.877 in this case). That only for referencing, after founding that, I want to extract the next line which its second column is non zero (4.152).

So I would like to get 1.95329810 and 4.152 as output, so I can substract them and get:

```
band_gap=4.152-$fermi_energy
```

By taking in consideration @DopeGhoti s answer, I used his code with an if statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
fermi_energy=$(awk 'NR==6 {printf $4}' DOSCAR-62.4902421.st)
awk -f go.awk DOSCAR-62.4902421.st
```

Where the `go.awk` file is:

```
BEGIN { 
test=0
}
NF == 3 && test == 0 && $2 != "0.0000E+00" {
   keptvalue=$1
}
NF == 3 && test == 0 && $2 == "0.0000E+00" {
   #print keptvalue
   test=1
}
NF == 3 && test == 1 && $2 != "0.0000E+00" {
   if ( sqrt(($fermi_energy-$1)**2) < 0.5 ) 
   {
       print $1
       test=0
   }
}
```

But I think that it is not the right way to use bash variables inside an awk script.

P.D. **In the case you are wondering**, the data represents the calculations of the [Density Of States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states) of the electrons of an oxide. The first column represents the electron's energies, the second the electron's amount in that energy level. Therefore, when looking for the next non '0.0000E+00' value since the closest level of the [Fermi Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level), we can calculate the energy required to make the electrons jump and conduct electricity. (Metals have zero band gap, thus they do not need energy input to conduct electricity)

Comment: `awk 'NR==6 {fermi_energy=$4}; /1.877/ {print $1-fermi_energy}'`, but I don't think this solves your problem. Given the input file above, what would be the expected output? What makes 1.877 special (why do you need to take the value from there)? What is special about 4.152, are there more values to follow?

Comment: Printing `1.877` on a line that contains `1.877` is just `/1.877/ {print "1.877"}` . But I really assume the numbers you mention aren't constants, but that there's some other rule you want to use. Why don't you tell what the actual logic is. It's also probably easier to implement all of this in `awk` instead of mixing `awk` and the shell

Comment: Also, show what output you want to see

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation of the problem. I edited the question.

Comment: The correct way to use a `bash` variable within an awk script would be e. g. `foo="foo bar"; awk -v foo="$foo" ' END { print foo }'`.  `awk` doesn't inherit environment variables from `bash`, you have to explicitly set them.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do what you appear to want, given the lack of sample output:

```
awk 'NF == 3 && $2 != "0.0000E+00" { print $1 }' /path/to/input
1.726
1.877
4.152
4.303
4.455
```

If you are actually asking for the first field on the last line where the second field is *not* (mathematically) zero which *is* followed by a record where the second field *is* (mathematically) zero, followed only by the first field of the first subsequent record where the second field is again *not* (mathematically) zero..  this is also doable with a relatively simple `awk` script:

```
$ cat go.awk
BEGIN { 
  test=0
}

NF == 3 && test == 0 && $2 != "0.0000E+00" {
  keptvalue=$1
}

NF == 3 && test == 0 && $2 == "0.0000E+00" {
  print keptvalue
  test=1
}

NF == 3 && test == 1 && $2 != "0.0000E+00" {
  print $1
  test=0
}
$ awk -f go.awk input
1.877
4.152
```

Comment: That helped a lot! Now I learned something... but it was not (yet) my desired output. I edited the question.